# Python Selenium webelement not displaying text

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I'm trying to use the following code to get some location from a website. Using the get_element function grabs the data I'm interested in, but it is only useful to me if I can index to each line. Splitting along a carriage return doesn't work so I tried using the get_elements function to create a list of the child tags. however as you can see from the output, I am only being given a single blank character for each line. Any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
elementBox = browser.find_element_by_id('dt')
elementList = elementBox.find_elements_by_tag_name('br')
print(elementBox.text, 'box')

scrapedLocation = []

for element in elementList:
scrapedLocation.append(element.text)                          
print(element.text, 'element')
```

Output:

```
*01-A "WP01-A" added
10 S 584607 4130707
37.31917°N -122.04511°E
Elevation= 91.5m box
 element
 element
 element
 element
 element
```

HTML:

```
onclick="gp.hhfoc(10020)">*20-T "WP20-T"
<br> 
11 S 384713 3760527
<br> 
33.97898°N -118.24806°E
<br>
Elevation= 48.6m
<br><br>
```

Comment: Could you post website link you are crawling?

Comment: There is no problem in your output. `<br/>` is a break line; and you try to print text of `<br/>` which doesn't have any content.

Comment: That makes sense! Is there a way to break up the output of the find_element function? There are no other tags associated with data I'm interested in

Comment: Post the html of concerned area so that one can help